# Looking for introduction to equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, reference-request, education

I am a beginner with Mathematica. I wanna learn how to make a program to solve a system of algebraic equations related to my master [?], so I am looking for a way to learn this in as little time as possible. How should I start?

Comment: [ref/Solve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) ?

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EquationSolving.html

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your question is too broad and goes against the policy against *"Chatty, open-ended questions "* , Please read ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  Your question may be put [on-hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e **it is too broad**. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

1. On the home page of the Documentation Center, click on the orange button, Symbolic & Numeric Computation.
2. In the pop-up menu that appears, click on Equation Solving.

Comment: Do you mean i write the phrase Symbolic&Numeric Computation in the search bar ?@m_goldberg

Comment: @HussienMohamed. No, just do what I wrote. Those colored rectangles on home page are all buttons and bring up menus.